# Optional find() parameter in MongoDB when searching for values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Basically what I am trying to do is say to my query that I want all of the users that have isBoosted = True to be first and after that, all others.

Thank You!

Comment: did the answer by Jose Lora solve your question?  If so, please award the answer points.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the method sort to order descending because true=1 and false=0 like this:

```
db.users.find().sort("isBoosted", -1)
```

Or

```
db.users.find([your filter criteria]).sort("isBoosted", -1)
```